# How can I change reducer output name for partition in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

In my hadoop programming I want to provide custom output name for the reducer lets say here is the code snippet

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Partitioner;

public class Partitionclass extends Partitioner<Text, IntWritable>{



    @Override
    public int getPartition(Text key, IntWritable value, int numreducetasks){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Job job=null;
        Configuration conf=new Configuration();
        try {
            job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(numreducetasks==2)
        {
            String partkey=key.toString();
            int val=Integer.parseInt(partkey);
            if(val%2==0)
            {
                //System.out.println("Even"+val);
                job.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.output.basename", "Even");
                return 0;


            }
            else
            {
                job.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.output.basename", "Odd"); 
                return 1;

            }
        }
        else if(numreducetasks==1)


        return 0;
        else
            System.out.println("Please give reduce task at least one");
        return -1;
    }

}
```

I tried it through Driver Class ,but It dint work so I create Job for in partition class but still is not working .I want Output file name as say For Odd
odd-r-00000 and for Even ,Even-r-00001.Can any one please tell me exactly how can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

It is provided in hadoop doc. Here - http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html

Use it as follows.

```
reduceMethod(){
.
.
.
.
 multipleOutputs.write(key, value, generateFileName(key,value));
 }

String generateFileName(Text key, IntWritable value){
 return key.toString() + "_" + value.toString();        
}
```